# How to implement this grails/gorm like hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

The hbm.xml looks like this, How can I implement the equivalent GORM class? Does "belongsTo" can specify which column to map?

I don't know much about hibernate, is the declaration in HBM a bidirectional data binding or not? That is, if I delete the goods, will the comment be deleted?

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mictest.model">
    <class name="CommentInfo" table="CommentInfo" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">

    <id name="commentId" column="CommentId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
<property 
    name="goodsId" 
    column="GoodsId" 
    update="true"
    insert="true"
    type="java.lang.Integer"
    not-null="false" 
    unique="false" 
    length="10"/>
<many-to-one name="goods" class="com.mictest.Goods" fetch="select" insert="false" update="false">
    <column name="goodsId" />
</many-to-one>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: you should first read a bit of info, see some examples and experiment yourself. That's the best way to learn. Just try out some options.

Answer (score 0):

not tested but something to start with.

```
package com.mictest.model

class CommentInfo {

static belongsTo = [goods: Goods]


static constraints = {
    goods nullable:false
}

static mapping = {
    id name:"commentId"
    table "CommentInfo"
    goods column: "goodsId", cascade:'save-update'
}
}


package com.mictest.Goods

class Goods{

    // other goods properties here

    static hasMany = [comments: CommentInfo]

}
```